# How do I traverse through model relationships in laravel with dot syntax

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to traverse through complex eloquent model relationships/attributes, and I'd like to use a simple dot structure to iterate through this, similar to how you can traverse arrays with `Arr::get()`

Example:

```
$data = [
  'foo' => [
    'bar' => [
      'key' => 'value'
    ]
  ]
];
$value = Arr::get($data, 'foo.bar.key'); // returns 'value'
```

I've tried using

```
$value = Arr::get($model, 'relation.subrelation.attribute')
```

However this fails and aways returns null, even though eloquent models support ArrayAccess.

Does laravel have a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Because relations could be one to many , there could be an array of objects with numeric indices. check if thats the issue.

Comment: @anwerjunaid these are purely one-to-one relationships (child/parent), but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Are you changing the Collection from the model query to Array? you should use `->toArray()` on the collection first.

Comment: Oh I miss this functionality. to-many could just return arrays as the result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all those wondering, I've managed to figure out a solution by modifying the arr::pull() function to work specifically with models:

```
public static function traverse($model, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (is_array($model)) {
        return Arr::get($model, $key, $default);
    }


    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $model;
    }

    if (isset($model[$key])) {
        return $model[$key];
    }

    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
        try {
            $model = $model->$segment;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return value($default);
        }
    }

    return $model;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Eloquent Models return a `Collection` which is not the same as Array in PHP. You can convert it to array using `toArray()` function

```
$my_model->toArray();
```

This then gives you an Array. But remember that it converts all nested models inside the main model into an array as well.